# Employee Supplier Name Mass update- fusion Procurement Cloud

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-apps

I wanted to update all the active employee supplier names in a specified format.

example : Employee First Name + Last Name - Employee Number

we are on fusion Procurement Cloud Revision 13.18.05 (11.13.18.05.0)

is there a way we can achieve this through supplier import process with FBDI template .

Kindly help me with the approach.

Comment: Why not just raise a SR for this. Oracle Sales Cloud/Fusion is a oracle product and you will find help much quickly on metalink

Comment: Thanks for the response! I already raised the SR. Awaiting for the response